# Reuse app object in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to reuse the **app** object in flask within another module.

Currently my directory structure is:

```
/xampp/code/MenuMaster
    __init__.py
    menumaster
        __init__.py
        menumaster_app.py
        sqltables.py
```

My first `__init__.py` file contains:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some key here'
```

The second `__init__.py` file is empty.

`menumaster_app.py` uses this app object. `sqltables.py` also needs to use this app object.

This is my `.wsgi` file:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/xampp/code/MenuMaster')
from menumaster_app import app as application
```

I am currently receiving the error in `.wsgi`:

```
 File "C:/xampp/htdocs/flaskapp/flask.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
 from menumaster_app import app as application   
 ImportError: No module named menumaster_app
```

If I change my `flask.wsgi` file to:

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/xampp/code/Menumaster/menumaster')
```

I get the error:

```
File "C:/xampp/htdocs/flaskapp/flask.wsgi", line 5, in <module>
from menumaster_app import app as application
File "C:/xampp/code/Menumaster/menumaster\\menumaster_app.py", line 44, in <module>
@app.route('/restaurants', methods = ['GET'])
NameError: name 'app' is not defined
```

If I am completely going about this the wrong way, I would love to hear the proper method to accomplish this.

Any help on this matter would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I have changed my file structure to:

```
menumaster_project
    menumaster
        __init__.py
        menumaster_app.py
        sqltables.py
```

`flask.wsgi`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, 'C:/xampp/code/menumaster_project')
from menumaster import app as application
```

`__init.py__`

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'some key here'
```

However, I am currently getting a `404` error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application is structured oddly.  A more common layout would be:

```
menumaster_project/
├─── menumaster/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── sqltables.py
│   └── my_subpackage/
│      ├── __init__.py
│      └── my_submodule.py
└── other_project_file.txt
```

Where `menumaster_project` would be on the Python path.  The app would be defined in `menumaster_project/menumaster/__init__.py`.  Importing app would be:

```
from menumaster import app as application
```